# How to set HTTP status code in JSP error handlers

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a JSP page (in Tomcat) which uses JSP Tags to retrieve some data. But these JSP Tags can throw exceptions (For example when parameter values are invalid). Now I want to implement a nicer error handling for these situation. I failed to find a way to GLOBALLY specify an exception handler (error-page definitions in web.xml don't work for exceptions thrown in a JSP). The only way I found so far is specifiying an errorPage attribute in the page header of ALL JSP-files.

```
<% page errorPage="/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/500.jsp" %>
```

Quite annoying to do this for ALL JSPs, but acceptable. But not acceptable is the fact that the error page is always delivered with a HTTP status code of 200. I want a 500 instead. I tried using a servlet as errorPage instead of a JSP and tried to set response.setStatus(500) and also response.sendError(500) but both calls seems to be ignored. So this code prints "200" two times and I have no idea why:

```
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
response.setStatus(500);
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

So the question is: How can I set the HTTP status code in JSP error handlers?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your error pages in `web.xml`.

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>
            500
        </error-code>
        <location>
            /500.jsp
        </location>
    </error-page>
```

in your `500.jsp`, set the directive as `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>`

Comment: As I wrote: error-page definitions in web.xml don't work for JSPs. I already have exactly these lines in web.xml to catch exceptions thrown in Servlets and it works fine there but my problem is exception-handling in JSP, not servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `setStatus(500)`, you'd better use `sendError(500)` - there are some differences.
The config in `web.xml` works fine with `sendError`, however, if you don't want the config in `web.xml`, `error-page` from page directive worked just for exceptions for me, not for HTTP error codes.