# ajax ready state reachs 4 but status always is 200

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, safari, onreadystatechange

my ajax code is:

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            alert("200");               
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 8001) {
            alert("8001");               
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 8000) {
            alert("8000");             
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 7000) {
            alert("7000");                
        }
        else {
            alert("x");              
        }
    }
};
xhr.open("POST","URL",true);
xhr.send(null);
```

and my code in page that i addressed in xhr.open is:

```
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("SATI_UID") == null) {
        response.sendError(8000);
    } else {
            response.sendError(8001);
    }
```

it works in firefox and chrome and ie but in safari i always get status 200. 
i use safari 5.1.7. i also use `response.setStatus` instead of `response.sendError` but it's not working.
anybody knows why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the status of the response server side, on your servlet.

The AJAX client will get the response and store the status code on [xhr.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties).

It is supposed to be a valid [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Don't forget the response code has to be set before the response is commited and any headers are sent.

You might want to use [HttpServletResponse#setStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)) or [HttpServletResponse#sendError](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int,%20java.lang.String)) to do so.

Or you may want to define an error page on your web.xml instead. Check out: [How to set HTTP status code in JSP error handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387379/how-to-set-http-status-code-in-jsp-error-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you use non standard http statutes. You should throw an error of the right type 4xx or 5xx (see [http status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) because this code has a real signification in the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1), and then in the body of the response set your own custom code for your error.

To sum up, the status code of the http response shouldn't be used to send your own status code because it breaks the protocol and can lead to some problem with middleware servers (like caching servers for instance).